# Ef code first complicate cascade delete scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cascade

I have this scenario: I have these classes:

```
public class A
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<B> bCollection {get; set; }
}

public class B
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

}

public class C1 : BaseClass1
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public virtual B B{get;set;}
}

public class C2 : BaseClass2
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual B B {get;set;}
}

...
 public class C100 : BaseClass100
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual B B {get;set;}
}
```

class A has collection of class B and class Ci have one class B **and different base classes**.
when in class A collection there is only B that Ci not reference it, I can delete class A and all the B collection also deleted(cascade delete). **But** when in class A collection there is B that classes Ci has reference to it I can't delete class A instance...

**My expected behavior:**

Class A will be deleted and all the B collection that class A has, and if Ci has reference to some of the B in the collection it will be null in the end of the delete.( class Ci intances will not be deleted!),
also I **don't want** to iterate throw all my Ci class to see if it has reference to the B collection that need to be deleted.

I don't want this code:

```
MyDbContext db=new MyDbContext();
Hash<int> bCollectionToDelete=GetBCollectionToDeleteHashSet();
var C1_db_collection= db.C1Collection.ToList();
foreach(var c1Item in C1Collection)
{
    if(bCollectionToDelete.Contains(c1Item.refrenceIdToB)
    {
       c1Item.refrenceIdToB=null;
    }
}

 var C2_db_collection= db.C2Collection.ToList();
foreach(var c2Item in C1Collection)
{
    if(bCollectionToDelete.Contains(c2Item.refrenceIdToB)
    {
       c2Item.refrenceIdToB=null;
    }
}

...
 var C100_db_collection= db.C100Collection.ToList();
foreach(var c100Item in C100Collection)
{
    if(bCollectionToDelete.Contains(c100Item.refrenceIdToB)
    {
       c100Item.refrenceIdToB=null;
    }
}
```

someone know how to achieve it?

Comment: Since there is no clean cascade, you will have to do it in your code. Something like `A.B.Where(b => b.C == null)` will probably fetch the correct entries for you.

Comment: but B doesn't has reference to C...

Comment: Well - let C know the IDs of the referenced B, then you can make a select of all to-be-deleted Bs to detect if they are in used in C. Or create the reference - it's your class isn't it?

Comment: yes it is my class, so there is no automatic whay to do it I need to iterate all my C instances and foreach C to check if its B is in the deleted B collection?

Comment: I think that last comment is really to the point.  I would suggest asking the opposite way and see if you can answer it:  if the connection between B & C is only stored in C, where else should it be seen?

Comment: @Mike I understand what you saying and that is why I made a bounty because I also can't think of something else, but maybe someone will have a "magic" solution that I will not need to iterate 100 classes...

Comment: And also I think it breaks the Open/Close principle: tomorrow there will be more classes and this will result more changes in all the functions that checks if Ci has reference to B...

Comment: I don't know a lot about how EF might automate this, but if you have to do it manually, certainly you can have your own "index", in terms of any .net collection that supports named access.  But it seems like the most direct thing, if not automatic, would be to add the reference inside B.

Comment: I can't have reference in B because each Ci instance can have reference to the same B, that's mean I should have 100 Lists in B...thats not sound reasonable...

Comment: The only solution I see here is to have a List of all the C's and have C implement iDispoable to destroy the B's and whenever a C gets created add it to the List of C's

Comment: is it possible to have the nullable foregin key to `B` in those `Ci` classes?

Comment: yes, you mean that in c you will have a forign key to B and is nullable?

Comment: @ilayzeidman yes. In that case, Can't you configure a `On Delete Set Null` for that?

Comment: @ilayzeidman are you using fluent API for configuring the entities?

Comment: yes I do use mix of fluent API and data annotation

Comment: The basic problem here is EF don't have an option to configure the cascade action for delete and update. So you'll have to manually update that for each table either via code or management studio.

Comment: This looks like a pretty gnarly model.

Comment: I dont know what is gnarly...:) but this is not my model but my model have this scenario...

Comment: you are setting all the C classes deriving from different BaseClass is this the case or all the C classes derive from the same class?

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid yes different base classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a case where you write a stored procedure to handle your cascading delete logic, and the EF code just makes a single call to the 'DeleteMyObject' sp and then your ef code will need to refresh its context to reload the changes immediately after.

You will pay a slight performance penalty to refresh your context, but if I had to guess moving the logic to an sp, and the performance gain of doing inter-related deletes there, will more than offset the small performance penalty of having to refresh.

Not sure if SP's are an option for you, but they are there to use when you need them.

EDIT:

Very simplified example of stored procedure that accepts the primary key of a table 'MainTable' and then deletes any related records, if they exists, from 3 'ChildTables'. You actual logic may be a bit more complicated:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteMyObject @Id INT
as
   BEGIN TRAN
     delete from ChildTable1 WHERE ParentId=@Id
     delete from ChildTable2 WHERE ParentId=@Id
     delete from ChildTable3 WHERE ParentId=@Id
     delete from MainTable WHERE ID=@Id

   COMMIT TRAN
```

Example of calling SP that is not mapped into your EF model:

> SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@Id", 12345);
>   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DeleteMyObject @Id",param1);

Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Comment: I don't really familiar with this can you bring a link that explain this approach?

Comment: Are you not familiar with SP's at all? or how to call them from EF?

Comment: I will try it in the next days from the point of performance anyway +1 for the research...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching in all C Classes you could let B remove him self

### by using an interface

```
public interface IRemoveB
{
    void RemoveB();
}

public class C1 : BaseClass1, IDeleteB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }

    #region IDeleteB Member

    public void RemoveB()
    {
        this.B = null;
    }

    #endregion
}


public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IDeleteB>  list{ get; set; }

}
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> bCollection { get; set; }

    public void prepareForDelete()
    {
        foreach (var item in bCollection)
        {
            foreach (var deref in item.list)
            {
                deref.RemoveB();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### by using an delegate

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<B> bCollection { get; set; }

    public void prepareForDelete()
    {
        foreach (var item in bCollection)
        {
            item.RemoveMe();
        }
    }
}


public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler Remove;

    public void RemoveMe()
    {
        EventHandler removeHandler = Remove;
        if (removeHandler != null)
        {
            removeHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
public class C2 : BaseClass2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private B internB;

    // maybe you need an otherform to set B because of your virtual 
    public B B
    {
        get { return internB; }
        set
        {
            if (internB != value)
                if (internB != null)
                    internB.Remove -= this.RemoveB;
                else if(value != null)
                    value.Remove += this.RemoveB;
            internB = value;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveB(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        internB.Remove -= this.RemoveB;
        B = null;

    }
}
```

### Edit:

to Answer your Question's

*`You mean thet every ci inherit from the same interface?`*
Yes exactly. [Here are more information about Interface](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/why-are-interfaces-useful)

*`and if yes ICollection<IDeleteB> is stored in the database?`*
No it only exist in your program. Think of it like a temporary 1:N referenztable

*`and in the delegate example how it is store in the database?`*
No it's basically the same think like the Collection

and this only work if `B in A == B in C` which does mean it's the same [instance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/new) of the Class B

Comment: Sound interesting your example is not completely clear to me can you clear yourself?

Comment: what do you want to know ? (which part isn't clear enough so i can focused on that :) )

Comment: You mean thet every ci inherit from the same interface? and if yes ICollection<IDeleteB> is stored in the database? and in the delegate example how it is store in the database?

Comment: ah i see my mistake. I thought we talk always about the same B object in A and C, but when `B in A != B in C` you cant use my solution the only way i can think of is a static `List<B>` where A and C get's there B's from so `B in A == B in C`

Answer (score -2):

you can set the option of the delete cascade to true for each class Ci in the method OnModelCreating by adding the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // for each class Ci write the following
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ci>()
            .HasRequired(t=>T.B)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

by this the delete will delete the Ci for you if exists with the B class
hope it will help you

Comment: I think you missed the row: "and if Ci has reference to some of the B in the collection, it will be null in the end of the delete", I mean I dont want to delete the ci instance...

Comment: yes since on deleting B => all Ci will be deleted by cascade automatically